# Notification popup in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file in which operators have to input data.

However, sometimes they forget to do so.

I already had the file start as soon as they log into their workstation, but I need to have a reminder "bothering" them.

Managed to have a MsgBox popup at a set time.

Is it possible to have it working like an Outlook reminder?

This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
    Application.OnTime "08:30:00", "DisplayAlarm"
End If

End Sub

Sub DisplayAlarm()
    MsgBox "Don't forget to input your data!", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be easier to insert an appointment in their Outlook calendar. By scheduling it and including them in the "meeting".

Comment: @FreeMan The thing is, they don't have access to Outlook.

Comment: Does this not already work? In what way do you want it to be like an outlook reminder?

Comment: @Ma.rcucciboy2 it works. However, if the operators log into their workstations later than 8.30 am, that reminder does not popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't think we really have to change much to get this working for you. If you are rather set on the 'main' alarm being at 8:30, then if they log in after that you can set it to remind them to add their info in an hour.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        If TimeValue(Now()) < TimeValue("8:30:00") Then
            Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:30:00"), "DisplayAlarm"
        Else
            Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("1:00:00"), "DisplayAlarm"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub DisplayAlarm()
    MsgBox "Don't forget to input your data!", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

If you just want it to notify everyone after an hour of waiting, you can use this instead.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("1:00:00"), "DisplayAlarm"
    End If

End Sub

Sub DisplayAlarm()
    MsgBox "Don't forget to input your data!", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```